# touching a modified file using touch and watch with grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, touch, watch

The title may be contradictory but let say i have a software (**s1**) [WYSIWYG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) but this software is not really *WYSIWYW (what you see is what you write)*, when editing the source file and saving, the software is not updating the result frame.

However if another software (**s2**) is touching the file, **s1**'s result frame is updated and now what you see is what you get (some kind of trick ye..).

I am using `grunt-contrib-watch` to watch a certain set of files, let say it is **s2** in my scenario. When I edit a being-watched file in **s1**, i want the watcher to execute a task that touches this file as well so **s1** is showing the result.

this is basically the code i want :

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({

        touch: {
            src: "the being-saved '.cf' file" // how can I reference this file ?
        },
        watch: {
            files: ['**/*.cf'],
            tasks: ['touch']
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-touch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
};
```

when i edit and save a `.cf` file I want the watcher to execute the touch task touching the `.cf` file that has just been saved.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried touching the file on *watch* event? Use this approach to perform grunt tasks selectively on files.

You can play around with this kind of setup:

```
grunt.event.on('watch', function(action, filepath) {
    //filepath is what you need

    //do the touch here. ie: set the src of touch task
    grunt.config('touch.src', filepath);

    //do some more work if needed
    //...

    //tell watch what to do
    grunt.config('watch.tasks', 'touch');
});
```

You might have to add nospawn to *watch* task to have it run in the same context:

```
options : { nospawn : true }
```

Hope this helps!